# Firebase notification override on receive Xamarin form

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have created an application in which I am able to receive notifications, but the problem is when I get a notification and at the same time I get another notification it overrides the first one? I know have to do something with this code and if anyone would help me I'd appreciate it.

```
CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnNotificationReceived += (s, p) =>
        {

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Received");

        };
```

in this it will just debuge and show and the notifcation is received, but i need to do something when notification receive it shouldn't override the 1st one

Answer (score 0):

Send firebase notification using data tag and when you receive data then show custom notification popup using this GitHub [library](https://github.com/edsnider/LocalNotificationsPlugin), for the more information refer this firebase [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message), like how to send notification using HTTP calls.

```
{
    "to" : "<TOKEN>....",
    "notification" : {
    },
     "data" : {
     "body" : "Welcom to Xamarin App",
     "title" : "Testing"
     "documentId" : "myId001"
   }
}
```